# Did sorcerers have genuine power or were people simply gullible

Tags: miracle, sorcery-magic-kishuf

Did sorcerers have genuine power or were people simply gullible.
Perhaps they discovered things like electricity or magnetism that people of that time would think were magical.
However I'm thinking of the Egyptian magicians duplicating the first few plagues and the witch of Endor resurrecting Shmuel for example.
As well as Tenach, the Talmud has lots of stories of rabbis performing miracles and Rabbi Akiva being worried about a sorcerer telling him his would die.  If it was all nonsense, Rabbi Akiva would not have cared.

Comment: It was probably a mix. Some were charlatans, some did real optical illusions and some had genuine evil power.

Comment: The best answer I know to this question is that if magicians and curses had no power, why would Hashem have stopped Bilhaam from cursing Am Yisrael?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Black Magic by Pharaoh's Magicians](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4266/black-magic-by-pharaohs-magicians)

Comment: Ever regular people have limited power when they curse and Hashem gave Billam special powers

Comment: @JoshK Ibn Kaspi addresses that argument at length.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/110427/13438

Comment: What I'd like to know is whether there is any way to test whether people were capable of doing things in those days that they cannot do today.  One way to test would be to see if there are lots of reports citing similar occurrences in different places and at different times.  Even in medieval times, people referred to dybuks etc.  Again, the question is whether there are lots of reports of these things appearing in public- something akin to the Kuzari principle.  To sum up, has someone has scientifically investigated the possibility that the ancients could do things that we would call magical.

Comment: @Alex Isn't a major flaw in Ibn Kaspi's logic the fact that Jews had no idea about Balak and Bilaam until Moshe told them about it in chumash Devarim? They came, they tried, they went home. No Jews knew about it so no place to claim subjective attribution of curses.

Comment: @user6591 He seems to explain that they knew about it.

Comment: @user6591 I've heard that line of thought but I'm not convinced they didn't know. I mean, no one seems surprised when Moshe so casually mentions that one of the reasons to not marry Moav is that thing with Bilam? Perhaps the Moabite women knew and told when they came in the Pinchas story. Especially if you think like the Midrash that Bilam sent the women to cause harm because the curse failed.

Comment: @Double I'm not saying one can't invent situations where they knew, but the simple reading of the Torah would imply they didn't. Considering that, it's not easy to defend a possibly novel reading into the passages about the curses by ignoring this.  Regarding no one seeming surprised, we have no recording of any of their reactions to anything Moshe said in Devarim so the lack of their jaws dropping about this wouldn't be surprising.

Comment: @user6591 I'm saying the simple read is we don't know what they knew. There's no particular indication one way or another. As you said lots of their reactions, day to day minutiae, etc. aren't mentioned and neither is this. You assume they found out as late as possible in the text. I say they could have found out right away. We're all just speculating.

Comment: @Double I'm assuming that the same way that I assume they didn't know about anything they didn't experience. To assume they knew about civilizations in foreign continents or about people on a mountaintop near or far is imaginative to say the least.

Comment: @user6591 knowing about news in Moab and news in Tenochtitlan aren't comparable. You can't lump this in with everything else in the world. That's the whole point of my contention above. I want trying to convince you the Bnot Moav told, only that it's about as reasonable as anything else. Already in the war they specifically killed Bilam; plausibly they knew.

Comment: @Double I hear that. And if I had a vested desire to believe magic never existed I would be inclined to appreciate your point more. As it is though, I've never taken sides on this age old debate. As much as we believe in certain ancient supernatural events, we can believe in one more type. Or it could've been a scam.  If however we were stacking proofs for each side of the argument on a scale, I'm still of the opinion this event would weigh in on the proof to curses and other supernatural devises having been real side. Taking an Occams razor approach and not inventing points unmentioned.

Comment: @user65 I purposefully never mentioned magic here and haven't read the above referenced Ibn Kaspi. I'm just thinking about this local pshat issue about when the Jews knew. That's what I meant by "line of thought", sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: @Double I think it's all one big debate, I'd be being shocked if anyone believed in magic and not curses or vice versa. Having said that I didn't mean to write magic. In fact I caught myself once and corrected it, so just pretend I wrote curses and not magic. Thanks:)

Comment: I've put my comment as a new question on the myth site of stack overflow [here](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/6098/were-people-ever-able-to-do-what-we-would-call-magic)

Comment: @AlHal https://books.google.com/books/about/Ancient_Jewish_Magic.html?id=DpJlOHceIjMC